# stream of objects containing multiple properties question

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to solve the following:
Given a list of Data objects try, in a 'one shot' like operation, stream the list, such that the end result will be a generic object or a data object where each prop get its own sum/max/min:

```java
class Data {
    int prop1;
    int prop2;
    ...

    // constructor
    // getters and setters
}
```

For example, given a list of 2 Data objects as follows:

```java
List<Data> list = Arrays.asList(new Data(1,2), new Data(3,4));
```

If I apply max to the first property and sum to the second one the result is an object with prop1=3 and prop2=6 or `Data(3,6)`

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you please share your attempt (either with streams or loops) ?

Comment: You could use another `Data` object as an identity object for `Stream#reduce`, though to be honest with different sets of operations on different fields, it would probably be easier to either have separate streams, or a helper method  which accepts a reference to the field and the reducing operation you want (e.g. `IntStream#sum`)

Comment: You say in another comment that you would want to apply this for 10+ properties and u want this to be done in a single stream, i don't think there's a nice way to do it so perhaps you should just use a simple loop and have methods that would calculate the min/max/sum etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

After reading your comments I better understood what you meant and need. If your final goal is to create a `Data` which holds the result of multiple computations, then the stream operation `teeing` is still a viable solution.

However, since the operation `teeing` accepts only 2 downstreams and a merger `BiFunction` to merge their results, you need to nest your `teeing` calls to include in the first downstream one of the operations you need to perform; while in the second downstream another `teeing` call. Basically, every second downstream of each nested call uses a `teeing` operation until you're left with only two computations. Then, the merger function of every outer call takes the first downstream's result and the nested call's result, merges them together, and creates a new `Data` object with them.

Here is an example with a hypothetical `Data` class whose properties represent: min value, max value, average and sum:

```
@lombok.Data
class Data {
    private @NonNull int prop1Min;
    private @NonNull int prop2Max;
    private @NonNull int prop3Avg;
    private @NonNull int prop4Sum;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> data = List.of(
                new Data(1, 10, 100, 1000),
                new Data(2, 20, 200, 2000),
                new Data(3, 30, 300, 3000),
                new Data(4, 40, 400, 4000)
        );

        Data result = data.stream().collect(Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getProp1Min)),
                Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getProp2Max)),
                        Collectors.teeing(
                                Collectors.averagingInt(Data::getProp3Avg),
                                Collectors.summingInt(Data::getProp4Sum),
                                (avg, count) -> new Data(0, 0, avg.intValue(), count.intValue())),
                        (max, d) -> new Data(0, max.get().getProp2Max(), d.getProp3Avg(), d.getProp4Sum())
                ),
                (min, d) -> new Data(min.get().getProp1Min(), d.getProp2Max(), d.getProp3Avg(), d.getProp4Sum())
        ));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
Data(prop1Min=1, prop2Max=40, prop3Avg=250, prop4Sum=10000)
```

---

#### Previous Answer

It sounds like you're trying to retrieve some statistics from a stream of elements.

> I am trying [...] to stream the list, such that the end result will be a generic object or a data object where each prop get its own sum/max/min etc.

For this purpose, there is already the `IntSummaryStatistics` class which includes a set of statistics gathered from a set of int elements. To obtain this information, you just need to stream your elements and invoke the `collect` operation by supplying `Collectors.summarizingInt()`; this will return the statistics of your elements. Moreover, Java also provides `LongSummaryStatistics` and `DoubleSummaryStatistics` to retrieve statistics of long and double types.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
IntSummaryStatistics stats = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));

System.out.println("Count: " + stats.getCount());
System.out.println("Sum: " + stats.getSum());
System.out.println("Min Value: " + stats.getMin());
System.out.println("Max Value: " + stats.getMax());
System.out.println("Average: " + stats.getAverage());

//In case Data had not been designed in place of IntSummaryStatistics and it's an actual needed class, 
//then you could set up the properties you need from the IntSummaryStatistics
Data d = new Data();
d.setMinProp(stats.getMin());
d.setMaxProp(stats.getMax());
d.setSumProp(stats.getSum());


//--------- Data class --------- 

class Data {
    private int minProp, maxProp, sumProp;

    //... rest of the implementation ...

    public void setMinProp(int minProp) {
        this.minProp = minProp;
    }

    public void setMaxProp(int maxProp) {
        this.maxProp = maxProp;
    }

    public void setSumProp(int sumProp) {
        this.sumProp = sumProp;
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
Count: 10
Sum: 45
Min Value: 0
Max Value: 9
Average: 4.5
```

Comment: SummaryStatistics are cool, however with op's requirements you will have to stream twice over the list to get the statistics for his `prop1  &  prop2` which I belive is he trying to avoid _**"in one shot"**_

Comment: Basing on how he/she formulated the question, it sounded as if `Data` had been created in place of IntSummaryStatistics, maybe because he/she didn't know about the class. However, once retrieved the IntSummaryStatistics he/she just needs to assign the fields needed to the corresponding Data's fields. No need to stream twice. I'll updated my answer too.

Comment: Hi @Dan , in this case Eritrean is correct. the IntSummaryStatistics is not what I meant.
i am actually looking for somethign like the teeing collector but that can handle more than 2 properties - I am not sure it can from the API

Comment: Hi @gkatz It's more clear now. I just misunderstood. Does Eritrean's solution answer your question?

Comment: @Dan not yet :) like I wrote, my real Obj actually has 10+ properties. by looking at the teening collector API it looks like it will work only on 2 properties. maybe I am missing something but this is how I read this strange API :)

Comment: @gkatz I've updated my answer to generalize the teeing implementation for n properties

Comment: wow @Dan thanks a lot for the answer. this solve my issue. my next question migh be the million dollar one.
would it be easier to just loop (maybe also more readable)? and in the case of loop what performance tradeoffs would I have for one side or the other IYO?
thanks!

Comment: @gkatz in terms of overhead, streams always add more overhead in comparison with traditional loops. However, their overhead impact is incredibly small for average sets of data. So, I wouldn't really worry about it. You really need several elements to notice any difference.

Comment: @gkatz Instead, in terms of readability it could improve only if you have utility methods that already perform the operation that you need, so for example your result Data could look like, `result.setPropMax(getMax(vetProperties));` (where the `getMax()` performs the iteration) and so on for every other property. Personally, I would leave it like this (with streams). It is actually well readable with all the useful and self-explanatory operations offered by streams.

Comment: @gkatz In conclusion, I would go for the stream implementation. The overhead is basically the same, maybe slightly higher in some scenarios (but again with many data). While the readability is far better like this than with loops (personally speaking).

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying, in a 'one shot' like operation

You are looking for the [Teeing Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) introduced in Java 12. Given a list of Data, where a Data class is something like:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public class Data {
    int prop1;
    int prop2;
}
```

and a list:

```java
List<Data> data = List.of(
    new Data(1,10),
    new Data(2,20),
    new Data(3,30),
    new Data(4,40)
);
```

> the end result will be an generic object or a data object
>
> if I apply max to the first prop and sum to the second

You can use `Collectors.teeing` to get a new Data object with the result of your operations

```
Data result =
data.stream().collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.reducing(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getProp1))),
        Collectors.summingInt(Data::getProp2),
        (optionalMax, sum) -> new Data(optionalMax.get().getProp1(), sum)
));
```

Or something else, for example a `Map<String,Integer>`

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = 
data.stream().collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.reducing(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getProp1))),
        Collectors.summingInt(Data::getProp2),
        (optionalMax, sum) -> {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
            map.put("max_prop1", optionalMax.get().getProp1());
            map.put("sum_prop2", sum);
            return map;
        }
));
```

Comment: thanks @MC Emperor;

I think the teeing collector would have been great. 
however, In real life I have to apply what I Said to an object with about 15 properties... the teeing collector accepts only 2 if I understand corectly. is there something similar or a way to apply this to 10+ propeties?thanks!

Comment: You should prefer `Collectors.maxBy()` over `Collectors.reducing(BinaryOperator.maxBy())` btw (it does the same exact thing but is shorter)

Comment: You're welcome, @gkatz, but I think you should thank Eritrean, as they posted this answer (I only edited it to make it slightly better readable).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they're only *reducing* functions, then you could utilize `reduce` as well:

```java
Data someNewData = someData.stream()
    .reduce((Data l, Data r) -> {
        int a = l.prop1() + r.prop1();          // Find sum of prop1
        int b = Math.max(l.prop2(), r.prop2()); // Find max value of prop2
        int c = Math.min(l.prop3(), r.prop3()); // Find min value of prop3
        return new Data(a, b, c);
    })
    .orElseThrow();
```